# Java 8 streams calling a method using map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to clean up some data on every employee object.I am trying to do this but not able to achieve desired output. How to do it with Java8 stream feature?

```
bulkEmployeeClean( Collection<Employee> entities) {
  Collection<Employee> entities2 = entities.stream().map(employee->cleanEmployee(employee));
}


Employee cleanEmployee(Employee emp) {
  //clean the employee data 
}
```

My desired output is I want  clean up every employee  object with java 8 streams

I get below error:
ErrorType mismatch: cannot convert from void to Collection

Comment: What is your desired output and what result are you getting with your current approach? You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just iterate your objects and do the modifications?

```
bulkEmployeeClean( Collection<Employee> entities){
    entities.forEach(this::cleanEmployee)
}
```

Comment: I get this exception Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Collection<Employee>

Comment: `Collection<Employee> entities2= entities.stream().map(employee->cleanEmployee(employee))` this line is wrong. `map` will not return anything unless you collect is using the `collect` method. You can just do a `forEach`. Do you want to remove some Employee objects?

Comment: This fails         Collection<Employee> entities2=  entities.forEach(this::cleanEmployee);  ErrorType mismatch: cannot convert from void to Collection

Comment: Just do entities.forEach(this::cleanEmployee); get rid of entities2 altogether

Comment: If you are doing a `forEach`, you don't have to assign it to some other collection. Original collection will be modified. Just that. No need to assign it again.

Comment: @Imesha Sudasingha: to be correct, `map` *does* return something as it returns a `Stream` to allow chaining more operations.

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all map() is intermediate stream operation. You get back Stream from intermediate operations not a Collection.
2. Next streams are lazy init which means they will not execute until a terminal operation is run. So you need to have one terminal operation.
3. If you want back collection you can use terminal operation like `collect(Collectors.toList())`
4. You cannot modify the original collection when you are operating on its stream. You will get ConcurrentModificationException.

I would suggest use a filter option instead

```
List<Employee> activeEmployees = entities.stream().filter(employee -> employee.isActive()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This is if you want to clear out Employee object. If you need to edit in those you can just iterate on those and call clean method on each object.

Answer (score 1):

```
entities.stream()
        .forEach(employee->cleanEmployee(employee))
```